# I am attempting to upgrade from ember 1.7 to 1.13

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-1

I am trying to upgrade from an ancient version of ember `1.7` to the still ancient `1.13` and I am getting `.js` errors. I am not well versed with ember, to begin with, so all the help I can get will be appreciated.

I changed all instances of the code where it was using `Ember.View.extend` to `Ember.Controller.extend`

and since then, I am getting an error

`Cannot read property 'noSignedUpAppts' of undefined.`

### Appt.Ember.js

```
function initEmberApp() {
    Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('stringFormat', function (g11nString, str) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(stringUtil.format(g11nString, str));
    });
    ApptApp = Ember.Application.create({
        rootElement: "#appointmentWrapper"
    });
    ApptApp.Router.map(function () {
        this.route("main", { path: '/' });
        this.route("mainParam", { path: "/:val" });
        this.route('mainId', { path: '/mainId/:appt_id' });
        this.route('mainDirect', { path: '/mainDirect/:appt_id' });
        this.route("schedule");
        this.resource('userSchedule', { path: '/schedule/:user_id' });
        this.route('scheduleId', { path: '/scheduleId/:appt_id' });
        this.route('userScheduleId', { path: '/userScheduleId/:ids' });
        this.route('scheduleSpecific');
        this.route('scheduleSpecificId',{path: '/scheduleSpecificId/:appt_id'});
        this.route('scheduleDate', { path: '/scheduleDate/:date' });
        this.route('scheduleResource', { path: '/scheduleResource/:resource_id' });
        this.route("settings");
        this.route("campus");
        this.route("noAccess");
    });
    ApptApp.history = {name:'',view:'',param:null, isSchedule:false}

    initViews();
}

function initViews() {
    initMain(ApptApp);
    initSchedule(ApptApp);
    initSettings(ApptApp);
    initCampus(ApptApp);
    initNoAccess(ApptApp);
}
```

### ApptMain.js

```
function initMain(ApptApp) {

    ApptApp.MainController = Ember.Controller.extend({
        g11n: apptPortlet.g11n,
        ableToEdit: apptPortlet.ableToEdit,
        canManageSettings: apptPortlet.canManageSettings,
        canAdmin: apptPortlet.canAdmin,
        defaultDate: '',
        showMySchedule: false,
        apptId: '',
        isDirect: false
    });

    ApptApp.MainParamRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function (param) {
            var date = moment(param.val.replace(/-/g, '/'));
            return { defaultDate: (date.isValid() ? date.format('MM/DD/YYYY') : ''), showMySchedule: (param.val == 'myS') };
        },
        setupController: function (controller, model) {
            this.controllerFor('main').set('defaultDate', model.defaultDate).set('showMySchedule', model.showMySchedule).set('apptId', '').set('isDirect',false);
        },
        renderTemplate: function () {
            this.render('main');
        }
    });

    ApptApp.MainIdRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function (param) {
            var items = param.appt_id.split('|');
            var date = moment(items[1].replace(/-/g, '/'));
            return { apptId: items[0], defaultDate: (date.isValid() ? date.format('MM/DD/YYYY') : '') };
        },
        setupController: function (controller, model) {
            this.controllerFor('main').set('defaultDate', model.defaultDate).set('showMySchedule', false).set('apptId', model.apptId.toLowerCase()).set('isDirect', false);
        },
        renderTemplate: function () {
            this.render('main');
        }
    });
    ApptApp.MainDirectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function (param) {
            var items = param.appt_id.split('|');
            var date = moment(items[1].replace(/-/g, '/'));
            return { apptId: items[0], defaultDate: (date.isValid() ? date.format('MM/DD/YYYY') : '') };
        },
        setupController: function (controller, model) {
            this.controllerFor('main').set('defaultDate', model.defaultDate).set('showMySchedule', apptPortlet.apptSetting != 0).set('apptId', model.apptId.toLowerCase()).set('isDirect', true);
        },
        renderTemplate: function () {
            this.render('main');
        }
    });

    ApptApp.MainView = Ember.Component.extend({
        didInsertElement: function() {
            var controller = this.get('controller');

            if (this.processRedirect(controller))
                return;

            this.renderView(controller);
        },
        renderView: function (controller, isRerender) {
            if (isRerender) {
                apptFullCal.destroy();
            }
            var g11n = controller.g11n;

            apptFullCal.init({
                data: {},
                defaultDate: controller.defaultDate,
                showMonth: true,
                showWeekNav: true,
                allowEditing: false,
                calElem: $("#myCalendar"),
                showWknd: apptPortlet.showWeekends,
                updateWknd: apptPortlet.updateSettings,
                g11n: controller.g11n,
                listViewPageSize: apptPortlet.listViewPageSize,
                noApptMesg: controller.g11n.noSignedUpAppts,
                rerender: function () {
                    apptFullCal.reload();
                    $("#myNotifications").apptNotification('render');
                },
                editEvent: function(appt, isClick, revertFunc, rerenderAction) {
                    var resource = {};
                    if (appt.resourceId != '' && appt.resourceEdit)
                        resource = apptPortlet.getResource(appt.resourceId);
                    $.apptDetails({ controller: controller, appointment: appt, g11n: controller.g11n, resource: resource, canAddAttendees: apptPortlet.canAddAttendees, rerender: function () { rerenderAction(); $("#myNotifications").apptNotification('render'); } });
                },
                readonlySources: function (viewName) { return viewName == 'month' ? [{ url: 'rpc/appointmentsinfo/getcalendaraggregate' }] : [{ url: 'api/calendarevents?fullCalendar=true&filter=conflictable' }]; },
                postApptRender: function (appt, elem, view) {
                    if (appt.isReadOnly) return;
                    var item = elem.find('.fc-content');
                    item.html(appt.isOwner ? appt.attendeeInfo : (appt.resourceId != '' ? appt.resourceName : appt.owner));
                    if (view.name != 'month') {
                        item.append($("<span class='fc-cus-event-info'>").html(appt.title));
                    }
                    if (appt.id == controller.apptId) {
                        controller.apptId = '';
                        apptFullCal.triggerClick(appt);
                    }
                    if (appt.newCommentCount > 0) {
                        var ctr = view.name == 'list' ? elem : item;
                        var comTxt = $("<span class='fc-comment'>").append($("<i class='fa fa-comment'/>")).append(view.name == 'list' ? stringUtil.format((appt.newCommentCount == 1 ? controller.g11n.newComment : controller.g11n.newComments), appt.newCommentCount) : '');
                        ctr.prepend(comTxt);
                    }
                },
                changeView: function(viewName) {
                    if (viewName == 'list')
                        $(".apptKeyInfo.otherEvents").hide();
                    else
                        $(".apptKeyInfo.otherEvents").show();
                    if (viewName == 'month')
                        $(".apptKeyInfo.otherEvents").removeClass("inactiveItem");
                    else
                        $(".apptKeyInfo.otherEvents").addClass("inactiveItem");

                    bindHelpText(g11n, viewName == 'list' ? '2' : (viewName == 'month' ? 0 : 1));
                }
            }, 'month');

            bindHelpText(g11n, 0);

            $("#myNotifications").apptNotification({
                g11n: apptPortlet.g11n,
                baseUrl: apptPortlet.baseUrl,
                renderFullTxt: true,
                callback: function(apptInfo) {
                    var date = moment(apptInfo.start);
                    if ((date.weekday() == 0 || date.weekday() == 6) && apptPortlet.showWeekends == false)
                        apptFullCal.showWeekends($("#myCalendar"), true, date);
                    controller.set('apptId', apptInfo.id);
                    apptFullCal.gotToDate('agendaDay', date);
                }
            });

            $("#peopleChooser").peopleChooser({
                peopleSource: 'rpc/appointmentsInfo/GetUserSearch',
                watermark: controller.g11n.watermark,
                onSelect: function(person) {
                    if (person.isResource)
                        controller.transitionTo('scheduleResource', person.id);
                    else
                        controller.transitionTo('userSchedule', { id: person.id, imgUrl: person.imgUrl, name: { full: person.fullName } });
                }
            });

            if (controller.canManageSettings || controller.canAdmin)
                $(".permissionAction").click(function() { ApptApp.history = { name: '', view: 'main', isSchedule: false }; });

            var schLinkAction = this.bindScheduleLink;
            $(".permHosts").hide();
            if (apptPortlet.canManageSettings && (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2 || (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 3 && apptPortlet.resourceId.length > 0))) {
                var resource = apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2 ? null : apptPortlet.getResource(apptPortlet.resourceId);
                if (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2 || (resource != null && resource.canEdit)) {
                    $(".permHosts").show().find('a').html("<i class='fa fa-group'></i>" + (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2 ? g11n.apptHosts : g11n.managersAndHosts))
                        .unbind('click').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $.apptManageHosts({
                                g11n: controller.g11n,
                                resource: resource,
                                isResource: resource != null,
                                portletId: apptPortlet.portletId,
                                onSave: function(res) {
                                    if (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2) {
                                        apptPortlet.hosts = res;
                                        schLinkAction(controller);
                                    } else {
                                        apptPortlet.hosts = res.hosts;
                                    }
                                }});
                        });
                }
            }


            if (controller.showMySchedule) {
                $(".mySchedule").hide();
                this.bindResourceInfo(controller);
            } else {
                $(".mySchedule").show();
            }
            this.bindSidebar(controller);
        },
        bindSidebar: function(controller) {
            var campus = $(".campusWrapper").hide();
            var myfac = $(".myFacWrapper").hide();
            $.get('rpc/appointmentsinfo/getsidebarinfo/', function (sidebarInfo) {
                if (sidebarInfo == null) return;
                if (sidebarInfo.campusResources != null) {
                    var ul = campus.find('#campusResources').empty();
                    for (var key in sidebarInfo.campusResources) {
                        ul.append($("<li>").append($("<a href='#'  class='activeItem apptStrong'>").data('id', key).html(sidebarInfo.campusResources[key]).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('scheduleResource', $(this).data('id')); })));
                    }
                    if (ul.find('li').length > 0)
                        campus.show();
                }
                if (sidebarInfo.currentFaculty != null && sidebarInfo.currentFaculty.length > 0) {
                    myfac.show();
                    var container = myfac.find(".myFacUsers").empty();
                    $.each(sidebarInfo.currentFaculty, function (i, fac) {
                        var div = $("<div class='myFac'>");
                        div.append($("<a class='activeItem apptStrong'>").html(fac.name).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('userSchedule', { id: fac.id, imgUrl: fac.imgUrl, name: { full: fac.name } }); }));
                        if (!fac.hasAvailAppts)
                            div.append($("<span class='pc-details'>").html(controller.g11n.noAppt));
                        $.each(fac.sections, function (j, sec) {
                            div.append($("<div class='inactiveItem itemInfo'>").html(sec));
                        });
                        container.append(div);
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        processRedirect: function (controller) {
            if (apptPortlet.name == null) {
                controller.transitionTo("noAccess");
                return true;
            }
            if (controller.isDirect) return false;

            var date = controller.defaultDate != null && controller.defaultDate != '' ? moment(controller.defaultDate).format('MM-DD-YYYY') : null;
            if ((apptPortlet.resourceId != '' || apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2) && !controller.showMySchedule) {
                var url = apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2 ? 'scheduleSpecific' : 'schedule';
                if (controller.apptId != '' || date != null) {
                    controller.transitionTo(url + "Id", (controller.apptId + '|' + date));
                }
                else
                    controller.transitionTo(url);
                return true;
            }
            else if (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 1 && !controller.showMySchedule && apptPortlet.hosts != null && apptPortlet.hosts.length > 0) {
                var host = apptPortlet.hosts[0];
                if (controller.apptId != '' || date != null) {
                    controller.transitionTo('userScheduleId', host.id + '_' + ((controller.apptId == '' ? ' ' : controller.apptId) + '|' + date));
                }
                else
                    controller.transitionTo('userSchedule', { id: host.id, imgUrl: host.imgUrl, name: { full: host.name } });
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },
        bindScheduleLink: function (controller) {
            var showLink = false;
            if (apptPortlet.resourceId != '') {
                var resource = apptPortlet.getResource(apptPortlet.resourceId);
                $(".scheduleLink").html(stringUtil.format(controller.g11n.bckToSchedule, resource.name)).unbind('click').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('schedule'); });
                showLink = true;
            }
            else if (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 1) {
                var host = apptPortlet.hosts[0];
                $(".scheduleLink").html(stringUtil.format(controller.g11n.bckToSchedule, host.name)).unbind('click').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('userSchedule', { id: host.id, imgUrl: host.imgUrl, name: { full: host.name } }); });
                showLink = true;
            }
            else if (apptPortlet.apptSetting == 2) {
                var names = '';
                var userCount = apptPortlet.hosts.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < userCount; i++) {
                    names += " " + apptPortlet.hosts[i].name;
                    if (userCount > 1 && (userCount - i != 1)) {
                        names += userCount - i == 2 ? ", " + controller.g11n.and : ",";
                    }
                }
                $(".scheduleLink").html(stringUtil.format(controller.g11n.bckToSchedule, names)).unbind('click').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('scheduleSpecific'); });
                showLink = true;
            }
            if(showLink)
                $(".bckToSchedule").show();
            else
                $(".bckToSchedule").hide();
        },
        bindResourceInfo: function (controller) {
            this.bindScheduleLink(controller);

            var ul = $("#userSchedules").empty();
            if (apptPortlet.ableToEdit) {
                ul.append($("<li>").append($("<a href='#' class='activeItem apptStrong'>").html(apptPortlet.name.full).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('userSchedule', apptPortlet.id); })));
                $(".rg-sidebar").show();
            }
            $.get('rpc/appointmentsInfo/GetMySchedules/', function (schedules) {
                if (schedules == null) return;
                for (var key in schedules) {
                    ul.append($("<li>").append($("<a href='#'  class='activeItem apptStrong'>").data('id',key).html(schedules[key]).click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); controller.transitionTo('scheduleResource', $(this).data('id')); })));
                }
                if (schedules.length > 0)
                    $(".rg-sidebar").show();
            });
        }
    });
    function bindHelpText(g11n, screen) {
        $(".apptHelpWrapper").appointmentHelp({ g11n: g11n, isHost: apptPortlet.ableToEdit, portletId:apptPortlet.portletId, screen: screen });
    }
}
```

Comment: follow the release instructions (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v1.13.0). Let's see if you could find anything useful there.

Comment: How big is your app? If its not huge, have you considered a total rewrite on 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly used Ember `1.7` but only ever with `ember-cli`. Anyway, I can point out a couple of things I am pretty sure that you aren't doing correctly. First off:

> I changed all instances of the code where it was using
>   Ember.View.extend to Ember.Controller.extend

This does not make any sense. These are not comparable. If you meant `Ember.Component` that would make more sense but there's still not a 1:1 similarity. I would recommend studying the [Ember.View docs from 1.7](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/1.7/classes/Ember.View/properties/controller?anchor=controller) as well as that for components and controllers. You should also give a the [Ember.View deprecation](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v1.x/#toc_ember-view) guide a read through. The recommended upgrade path is to convert views to components, but components are isolated contexts unlike `Ember.View`. I think you will have to pass the controller to the `Ember.Component` instance (would be better to pass the properties needed). Since `Ember.Component` extends `Ember.View`, you might not be able to pass via the `controller` property directly (I don't know if this would be problematic but I would probably avoid).

Accessing data via `{{view.someProp}}` or `{{controller.thisThing}}` can nearly always be replaced by proper use of data passing and block params. See the guide on differences in yielded blocks for a complete example of using block params over the `{{view}}` keyword.

I would recommend going all the way through the deprecations guide to understand what needs to change.

Comment: The project is not huge but I was trying to avoid a total rewrite. Looks like I can't however. Thanks for your advice/guidance.

Comment: I think if you took the time to understand the 1.7 architecture, you'd be able to transition the code. But that will take some time and effort. And some form of rewriting/major refactoring will be necessary because a lot of changing happened in this upgrade time period with regard to the rendering, removal of views, etc. What's in 1.13 for you?